# How to get first date and last date of previous month in php?

Tags: php

I want to get previous month first date and last date.

```
$first_date = strtotime('first day of previous month', time());
$previous_month_first_date=date('Y-m-d', $first_date);
$previous_month_last_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));
```

Comment: If you have many things to do with date & time, you can use [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs). It has lots of function to manipulate date time.

Answer (score 6):

=> Try this code I hope it's useful ..

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'));

echo "<br/>";

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month'));
```

Output:- https://eval.in/925253

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of previous month'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Get last day of any other month
Enter any month/day/year to get the last day of that month

```
$lastday = date('t',strtotime('3/1/2009'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already getting the first date of previous month by:

```
$first_date = strtotime('first day of previous month', time());
```

Just add ('Y-m-t') in date format to get last date of previous month:

```
$previous_month_first_date=date('Y-m-d', $first_date);
$previous_month_last_date=date('Y-m-t', $first_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$date_01 = date("Y-m-01",strtotime("-1 month"));  // last month first date
$date_02 = date("Y-m-01",strtotime("-0 month"));  // this month first date
$date_03 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($date_02))); // last month last date
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. `-1 month` just gets the current day of the previous month, not the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it

```
$first_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of previous month'));
$last_date  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));
    echo $first_date;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $last_date;
```